# Apple Script: keydown doesn't affect game

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to use keydown to press a key in an emulator and a game however it is not being picked up.
However, notepad does pick up the keypress.

My Code:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to key code 13'
```

What can I do so my game/emulator can pick up the keydown?

Comment: **System Events** sends the `keystroke` or `key code` to the _window_ that's frontmost, is your game the frontmost _window_? If not, you need to `activate` it before sending the  `keystroke` or `key code` to the _window_.

Comment: it is the frontmost window

Comment: If it's frontmost and does not receive the `keystroke` or `key code` then **System Events** is probably not going to be able to do what you want. BTW the _code_ you show in your question doesn't `activate` any _windows_.